# configure reoccurring payment and one time payment for paypal using php

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I am working on a website which provides the subscription plans like for 1 year, 2 year and 3 year. User can make payment using the one time payment and using the monthly payment. for achieving this functionality I integrated reoccurring payment and one time payment using paypal gateway and I have successfully integrated. But I have some problem below is my scenario.

Suppose customer checkout using one time payment for one year subscription plan and make payment on paypal then paypal will hit at my IPN handler script and I will update the subscription plan for that customer for one year.

Now if customer checkout using the reoccurring payment for one year subscription plan then it will hit at my IPN handler script and i will update the subscription plan.

But here i want to know how i will differentiate with one time payment and reoccurring payment because whenever paypal hit the IPN for monthly payment then it will update my database for that customer and it will update the subscription date with one year. In this way it will update database every month and customer subscription date will update every month with one year.

I hope you can understand what i am trying to say,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The txn_type in your IPN will be different depending on the type of payment, so that's one way to distinguish between the two.  Configure your IPN to handle each txn_type different depending on what you need to do for one-time vs subscription payments.

Also, keep in mind that you can add an initial payment in to a recurring payments profile and it will be treated as a one-time payment.  Sort of like a setup fee when signing up for cable service or something like that.

Are you using the Recurring Payments API or Standard Subscription buttons or what?

Comment: Thanks for your answer and understanding my question. I am using Reoccurring Payment API using paypal express checkout.

Comment: Cool.  Yeah, setting up different logic in your IPN handler for the different txn_types would solve your issue.